# Timestamps on video references in biblatex/biber

Tags: biblatex, formatting, biber, date

Is there an easy way to get biblatex/biber to output the `date` field to include the *time*? I'm using `@video` (and `@photo`) which, as far as I can tell, lack drivers by default and so fall back to something equivalent to `@misc`.

I can specify the date in `yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS` format per the manual, but all of my attempts to set options (e.g. `dateusetime=1`) per various documents I've read have failed to produce the time in the references.

The context is a number of photos and video files with a timestamp in the corner where I'd like to reference the exact date and time of an event. I could write drivers for `@video` and `@photo`, but that seems like overkill if there's an easier solution that I've so far failed to find.

Much-requested MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{mwe1.bib}
@photo { img-noodles,
    author = {{Security Camera}},
    title  = {Suspect eating noodles},
    date   = {2016-01-01T15:43:21},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=none,dateabbrev=false,
    dateusetime=1,time=24h]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mwe1.bib}

\begin{document}
This is a test~\autocite{img-noodles}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE Output]

Edit: also included `@photo` and an obvious use case where a full timestamp is necessary (based on comments).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. It would be helpful if you could give a minimal compilable document showing the bibliography style you're using, and a sample `.bib` file entry that people could play with.

Comment: If we consider `@video` analogous to a `@book` and the time in the video corresponds to a page, then usually you would just reference the complete video without timestamp in the bibliography and add the exact timestamp in the citation: `\cite[3:33]{myvideo}`. In any case a short example document showing both which style you use and how you cite the video in question (including an example `@video` entry) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @moewe Yes, I am aware of that option. Alternatively, you could view a long video as a collection, compendium, or compilation of clips, each of which is cited separately, even though they're ultimately in the same "document". In this case, the "collection of clips/articles" analogy is preferred over the "cite a position/page" analogy.

Comment: Mhhh I guess I could buy the `@collection` interpretation if the video has *clearly* distinct scenes (acts, sub-clips, ... whatever, ideally those scenes are associated with different primary "authors", otherwise it is still a `@book` with different chapters). Anyhow, the `date` field would not be appropriate to give the position in the video. After all the `date` (usually) refers to the date of publishing a work. It would be more natural to define a new field for the timestamp (or if you can't be bother to do that abuse the `pages` field).

Comment: Please consider editing your question and adding a short example document that shows what you have so far, which style you use and what your `.bib` entry looks like at the moment (an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864,  https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Comment: Added MWE, although I honestly don't really see much point in it in this case. There's either an easy way to do this or I have to live with a hack or write a driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The second issue mentioned here (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/909) has been fixed in `biblatex` 3.13.
>
> Please update your TeX distribution to obtain current versions of `biblatex` and Biber.

There are two issues here

Firstly, `dateusetime=1,` does not enable `dateusetime`. The option expects the values `true` or `false`, anything that is not `true` will be treated as `false`.

But even with `dateusetime=true,` the output is not as expected since the default truncated date formats forgot about times. This is a bug that should be fixed in the next version of `biblatex`, see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/909. In the meantime it is probably easier to use one of the full date formats that supports printing the time. So for the time being you need an explicit `date=long` (or `date=short`, `date=ymd`, `date=iso`) to override the default `date=comp`, which drops the time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=none,
  time=24h, dateabbrev=false, dateusetime=true,]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@photo{img-noodles,
  author = {{Security Camera}},
  title  = {Suspect eating noodles},
  date   = {2016-01-01T15:43:21},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
This is a test~\autocite{img-noodles}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Security Camera. Suspect eating noodles. January 1, 2016 15:43.]

---

By default `biblatex` does not show seconds, this can be enabled with the load-time option

```
seconds=true,
```

Comment: That's great, thank you. Any idea how I might get it to display the seconds as well? This is much better and probably enough, but displaying seconds too would be ideal.

Comment: @Emmet The option `seconds=true,` should display seconds, see the edit.

Comment: That does the trick!  Thank you.